# Terminal connection error when running v.net.steiner

Tags: grass-gis, error, network, centos

I am using GRASS 7.6.0 on a CentOS server. I've attempted to run the v.net.steiner function on the map layer with the following properties:

```
Layer/table: 1/network
type       count        min        max
point          0          0          0
line       33893          1      32592
boundary       0          0          0
centroid       0          0          0
area           0          0          0
face           0          0          0
kernel         0          0          0
all        33893          1      32592
Layer: 2
type       count        min        max
point       3440          1       3461
line           0          0          0
boundary       0          0          0
centroid       0          0          0
area           0          0          0
face           0          0          0
kernel         0          0          0
all         3440          1       3461
```

When running v.net.steiner I recieve an error as follows:

```
v.net.steiner input=network arc_layer=1 node_layer=2 terminal_cats=0-3461 output=steinerout
Number of terminals: 3437
Number of Steiner points set to 3435
Building graph...
Registering arcs...
 100%
Flattening the graph...
Graph was built
ERROR: Terminal at node [30981] cannot be connected to terminal at node
       [2269]
```

Wondering why this might be happening.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found that when working with v.net.steiner tree the devil is most of the time in the lines layer. Something very common is to have gap in your network that are hard to find. In case you have a node in one of those unchaid lines, the tool makes that error. 
What you can do is correct the line layer using this tools:

1. v.clean (to correct topology error almost automatically).
2. Make a tiny buffer of lines (0.1m) and dissolve. Then make multipart to singlepart. With this you can go now to those lines that are alone. You can decide if you want to modify or get rid of.

[image]